# Are there technical reasons for an immediate update following a fresh download/install?

Tags: deployment, software-updates

I've had this happen in all sorts of software products: You purchase a software product, download it, install it, and then after the install, the program immediately begins downloading an update or a patch.

Ideally, I would imagine that the download package would somehow be linked to the product's repository so that stable releases could be pushed to the product site rather than having to force the user to wait through an update after install.

Are there any technical reasons for the install/update process or is it just a case of poor deployment infrastructure on the part of a lot of companies?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's not poor, deployment of the main install image and downloadable update/patch are different things.

You cannot expect software providers chase all their downloadable images at all the mirrors to be updated with the latest nightly build, although some do that.

Usually, a cut-off is being made for a release image, and until the next cut-off, the updates are provided as patches one by one and are being downloaded by the product after it installs.

Comment: For piece of software that I downloaded and installed today, it had 48 upgrade packs that I had to wait for it to download and install. Surely that must be poor deployment practices...

Comment: @Virtuosi: Depends on where you downloaded it from. I have had installers of my software copied onto all sorts of sites without my knowledge - one cannot expect me to keep all those copies up-to-date...

Comment: @Marjan - That's a good point.

Answer (score 1):

For software that is deployed through multiple channels, there can be different approval delays from submit to availability.

So as soon as you install it from channel X, it may check if there's a newer version and prompt to install again.

I've seen this several times with mobile software from app stores.

Answer (score 0):

In most cases, when software ships, it ships in stable form.  Once the software is installed, then at that time it phones home to check for an update.

More often than not, there are several factors that cause this...for example:

Operating Systems that come on disk probably already are behind the curve in updates, but the main goal is to get it installed first.

Another example is enterprise.  Big businesses want to install a product as-is, then slowly integrate the patches as-needed in controlled environments before just racing to the bleeding edge.

Being up-to-date isn't always a good thing.

Answer (score 0):

They don't want to rebuild the installer for the whole program every time there is a new security hole or bug found.  For one thing, the download would end up a lot bigger, and I assume it's easier to create a patch than to rebuild the whole installer.  And with installations on disk, there's a lot of money that goes into the making of those disks that would be wasted if they had to throw away the millions of them sitting in the warehouse every week just for a 5kb change to one file.

Also like the other answers state, it can be difficult to update all the different distribution sites.  I've seen old versions of games on some sites, when other sites have had updated versions for 6 months.

Comment: this answer does not appear useful because it looks that all its points are better presented in other answers to the question

Comment: @gnat I did not see in any other answer anything about the cost of replacing disks that were already made, or size of original download

Comment: "In most cases, when software ships, it ships in **stable form**... Operating Systems that come on **disk**... businesses want to install a product **as-is**..." ([quote source](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/106615/31260)) Don't get me wrong your answer _would_ be reasonably OK if that was original content, or at least better presentation of what was already written. But to me, this is not the case here sorry

Comment: @gnat Does that mention WHY it ships in stable form? Does it mention anywhere that COST to the developer is a factor?  And where does it mention the SIZE of downloaded installers or the HASSLE of rebuilding installers?  My answer touches on different aspects of those points...  that's like if someone says a bird flies because it has wings and someone else says it flies because it has an instinct to fly and calling those the same points

Comment: "WHY" - sure: "You cannot expect software providers chase all their downloadable images at all the mirrors..." (I leave it to you to find out where it sits). Again don't get me wrong - if you would present your considerations better than in other answers, I'd be the first to upvote. As of **[now](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/revisions/184061/1 "original revision of the answer")** though things don't look that way

Comment: @gnat That's not shipping in stable form, that's downloads and has to do with the hassle of updating 20 different mirrors, not the size of the installer, or anything to do with disks or even the cost I mentioned

Comment: oh! by the way your whole obsession with disks is another thing that makes me suspect answer usefulness. At least for me, disks are "corner case", last 3-5 years I rarely install from these

Comment: @gnat A lot of useful programs come on disk... and when you live in a rural area like me and use dialup you are more likely to buy a disk than try to download a windows service pack or even a game if there is the option to get it on disk.  People tend to not realize there is a large population of people that still use dialup, or have bandwidth limits.  Just because you don't use disks doesn't mean no one else does.